# Verify Median Value with Area Under the Curve Calculation

Tags: python, numpy, median, area

I want to calculate the area under this curve for confirmation that the size is correct. How would one go about doing this?

I have a frequency plot below. The package utilized for this median calculation is here: https://github.com/nudomarinero/wquantiles

```
def annot_median(Size,Count, ax=None):
    xmedian = weighted.median(Size, Count)
    ymedian = np.interp(xmedian,Size, Count)
    text="median " + "[{:.2f},{:.0f}]".format(xmedian, ymedian)
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=85")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="right", va="top")
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmedian, ymedian), xytext=(0.94,0.86), **kw)
    
annot_median(Size,Count)
```

I started with thinking the trapezoid method could be utilized to verify that value

```
x = Size
y = Count 
Area_t=np.trapz(x[:],y[:])
```

How can I write something so when Area_t = 0.5(total) print corresponding x and y values??

Comment: This question is a little too vague.  First, you need to determine the equation for the curve.  Second, you need to calculate the integral (calculus), which produces the area.  However, that would be an estimate, as this curve is only approximately a bell curve.  As an alternative, if you have every data point, you can calculate the area under point1 and point2 as approximately [(y1 + y2)/2] * (x2 - x1) and sum all of these.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a cumulative sum of the normalised area and the first point where this sum is >= 0.5.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import cumtrapz

# generate some heavy-tail data
np.random.seed(0)    
y, x = np.histogram(np.random.gumbel(size=100000), bins=1000)
x = x[:-1]

area = cumtrapz(y, x)
area = area / area[-1]
idx = np.argwhere(area >= .5)[0,0]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.vlines(x[idx], y.min(), y.max(), linestyles='dashed')
plt.show()
```

Which produces the result

[image: Plot result]

Where the median value occurs would then be at `x[idx]`, but this may not exactly agree with your other calculation. For one thing, if you have `N` points, the trapezoidal rule will produce `N-1` area segments. So you have to decide which x point represents which integral point. For example, you could map `x[1]` to `area[0]`. And with the cumulative sum you get the first point where the sum is greater or equal to 0.5. If it's sufficiently larger than 0.5 (0.503 in this case), you can interpolate a few `x` and `area` values near the median for a more accurate estimate of where `area` is 0.5.

Comment: that's great I made:for i in range(1, len(xs)):
    slope = (xs[i]-xs[i-1])/(ys[i] - ys[i-1])
    delta_x = x_sort[i] - x_sort[i - 1]
    delta_y =  ys[i - 1] + (ys[i-1] + delta_x * slope)
    sum = sum + (delta_y/2 * delta_x)
    b = slope*(ys[i] - ys[i-1])
    count = count + 1
    print( str(sum) + ','+ str(xs[i- 1])  + ','+ str(ys[i- 1] ))            in the meantime  hmm so I guess the numpy would essentially be the same but I am getting differing values so I gotta figure that out

Comment: @Connor If you take the median to be at `x[idx+1]` and linearly interpolate this point with the previous one to see where area is exactly 0.5, you should get the same answer as your other function because it's mathematically equivalent.

Comment: @Connor Explicitly, `p = (area[idx] - 0.5) / (area[idx] - area[idx-1]); x[idx+1] - p * (x[idx+1] - x[idx])`.